# Original proof of Hilbert's syzygy theorem

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, syzygies

Does anyone know an English reference for the original proof of Hilbert's syzygy theorem? The three proofs that I know use either:

- the theory of projective dimension and change of rings (plus a step to go from projective to free resolutions)
- the symmetry of the Tor functors
- Groebner bases

None of these tools would have been available to Hilbert, and I guess his original proof was much more direct. But, unfortunately, the original reference is in German. Is there an English proof somewhere?

Comment: I am unsure if this was Hilbert's original proof, but Arrondo's *Introduction to Projective Varieties* contains an elementary proof by induction on the number of variables.

Comment: Thank you, I had a quick look at it seems like the kind of argument that would have been available to Hilbert

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Theory of Algebraic Invariants](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&lr=&id=xCneO62aHiIC&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=Hilbert:+Ueber+die+Theorie+der+algebraischen+Formen+englisch&ots=FlulibiSC-&sig=FsB1P8lQZJKadWwt4l2HkZqldg4#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know there was an English translation

Comment: this is not a translation of Hilbert's publication on the syzygy theorem in the Mathematische Annalen (which I don't think exists), but a translation of lecture notes by Hilbert's student Sophus Marxsen

Answer (score 8):

Actually, there is an English translation of Hilbert's
"Über die Theorie der algebraischen Formen" (Mathematische Annalen 36, 473--530, 1890), where the theorem is in Part III of that five-part paper. The translation is in pages 143--224 of "Hilbert's Invariant Theory Papers", Volume VIII of R. Hermann's "Lie Groups: History, Frontiers and Applications", Math. Sci. Press, Brookline, MA, 1978. I don't know if the book is available on-line.